# How do I group XML nodes by attribute value as key using XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to the XSLT stuff. This is my XML -

```
<ROWS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ID"><![CDATA[111]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COL1"><![CDATA[john]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COL2"><![CDATA[]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COL3"><![CDATA[]]></COLUMN>                                           
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ID"><![CDATA[111]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COL1"><![CDATA[john]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COL2"><![CDATA[]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COL4"><![CDATA[xyz4]]></COLUMN>   
    </ROW>
     <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ID"><![CDATA[112]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COL10"><![CDATA[john]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COL11"><![CDATA[]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COL14"><![CDATA[xyz14]]></COLUMN> 
    </ROW>
</ROWS>
```

I would like to group the nodes by attribute value of ID. So the output will look like this -

```
<ROWS>
   <ROW>
      <COLUMN NAME="ID">111</COLUMN>
      <COLUMN NAME="COL1">john</COLUMN>
      <COLUMN NAME="COL2"/>
      <COLUMN NAME="COL3"/>
      <COLUMN NAME="COL4">xyz4</COLUMN>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <COLUMN NAME="ID">112</COLUMN>
      <COLUMN NAME="COL10">john</COLUMN>
      <COLUMN NAME="COL11"/>
      <COLUMN NAME="COL14">xyz14</COLUMN>
   </ROW>
</ROWS>
```

I am able to use the following XSLT 2.0 to achieve it -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="ROWS">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="ROW" group-by="./COLUMN[@NAME='ID']">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*" group-by="@NAME">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]" />
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I need to write this in XSLT 1.0 and I am having a hard time getting it to work correctly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best done using the Muenchian method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html There are many examples of Muenchian grouping here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:key name="Row-by-Key" match="/ROWS/ROW" use="COLUMN[@NAME='ID']"/>
    <xsl:key name="Row-by-Key-child-by-name-value" match="ROW/*" 
             use="concat(../COLUMN[@NAME='ID'],'+',@NAME)"/>
    <xsl:template match="ROWS">
      <ROWS>
        <xsl:for-each 
             select="*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('Row-by-Key',COLUMN[@NAME='ID'])[1])]">
            <ROW>
                <xsl:for-each  
                    select="key('Row-by-Key',COLUMN[@NAME='ID'])
                            /*[generate-id()
                                =generate-id(
                                    key('Row-by-Key-child-by-name-value',
                                        concat(../COLUMN[@NAME='ID'],'+',@NAME))[1])]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="self::*[node()|@*]"/>                
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ROW>
        </xsl:for-each>  
      </ROWS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XSLT for the inner grouping doesn't use the value, it has just the `group-by="@NAME"`, i.e. the `NAME` attribute as the grouping key. Your XSLT 1 above does differ by using the `NAME` attribute plus the value of the element as the grouping key, it might be that you want or need that but your XSLT 2 sample does not suggest that.

Comment: Good catch Martin! I will change it in XSLT 1. Thank you!